# Python empty dict not being passed by reference?

Tags: python, recursion

This sample is code is a bit odd, but bear with me...

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, internal_dict = None):
        self._internal_dict = internal_dict or {}

        for attribute_name in self.__class__.__dict__.keys():
            attr = getattr(self.__class__, attribute_name)
            if isinstance(attr, str) and attribute_name.startswith("a"):
                # We are iterating over all string attributes of this class whos name begins with "a" 
                self._internal_dict[attribute_name] = {}
                setattr(self, attribute_name + '_nested_object', Foo(internal_dict=self._internal_dict[attribute_name]))

class FooChild(Foo):
    ax = "5"
    ay = "10"

fc = FooChild()

print fc.ax_nested_object._internal_dict # This prints {}

fc.ax_nested_object._internal_dict['123'] = 'abc'

print fc._internal_dict # This prints {'ay': {}, 'ax': {}}
```

I would have expected my `{'123' = 'abc'}` to have gotten through to the second print because the dictionary should have been passed into the recursive `__init__` call by reference.  However, if I change this line:

```
self._internal_dict[attribute_name] = {}
```

to this:

```
self._internal_dict[attribute_name] = {'test': 1}
```

Then I get the following printed:

```
{'test': 1}
{'ay': {'test': 1}, 'ax': {'test': 1, '123': 'abc'}}
```

Why does priming that dictionary data cause it to be passed properly by reference?

Comment: This is the exact reason I give people asking whether to include `is None` when checking whether an optional parameter was supplied. Thank you for confirming that this actually happens ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
self._internal_dict = internal_dict or {}
```

An empty dict is falsy, so you will get a *new* empty dict on subsequent recursive calls. That's why initializing the dict to non-empty (truthy) "fixes" it.

You want:

```
self._internal_dict = {} if internal_dict is None else internal_dict
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your class is the shortcut you are taking to assign the `self._internal_dict` variable.

Unfortunately for you, an empty dictionary has a truth value of false.

Your code works if you change your code to:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, internal_dict = None):
        if internal_dict is None:
            internal_dict = {}

        self._internal_dict = internal_dict

        for attribute_name in self.__class__.__dict__.keys():
            attr = getattr(self.__class__, attribute_name)
            if isinstance(attr, str) and attribute_name.startswith("a"):
                # We are iterating over all string attributes of this class whos name begins with "a" 
                self._internal_dict[attribute_name] = {}
                setattr(self, attribute_name + '_nested_object', Foo(internal_dict=self._internal_dict[attribute_name]))

class FooChild(Foo):
    ax = "5"
    ay = "10"

fc = FooChild()

print fc.ax_nested_object._internal_dict # This prints {}

fc.ax_nested_object._internal_dict['123'] = 'abc'

print fc._internal_dict # This prints {'ay': {}, 'ax': {}}
```