# Why does this empty dict break shared references?

Tags: python, dictionary, pass-by-reference

I have found some Python behavior that confuses me.

```
>>> A = {1:1}
>>> B = A
>>> A[2] = 2
>>> A
{1: 1, 2: 2}
>>> B
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

So far, everything is behaving as expected.  A and B both reference the same, mutable, dictionary and altering one alters the other.

```
>>> A = {}
>>> A
{}           # As expected
>>> B
{1: 1, 2: 2} # Why is this not an empty dict?
```

Why do `A` and `B` no longer reference the same object?

I have seen this question: [Python empty dict not being passed by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048802/python-empty-dict-not-being-passed-by-reference)  and it verifies this behavior, but the answers explain how to fix the provided script not why this behavior occurs.

Comment: Assignment binds a name to an object.  It doesn't mutate an object.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a pictorial representation *:

```
A = {1: 1} 
# A -> {1: 1}
B = A
# A -> {1: 1} <- B
A[2] = 2
# A -> {1: 1, 2: 2} <- B
A = {}
# {1: 1, 2: 2} <- B    
# A -> {}
```

`A = {}` creates a **completely new object** and reassigns the identifier `A` to it, but **does not** affect `B` or the dictionary `A` previously referenced. You should read [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), it covers this sort of thing pretty well.

---

Note that, as an alternative, you can use the [`dict.clear`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear) method to empty the dictionary *in-place*:

```
>>> A = {1: 1}
>>> B = A
>>> A[2] = 2
>>> A.clear()
>>> B
{}
```

As `A` and `B` are still references to the same object, both now "see" the empty version.

---

* *To a first approximation - similar referencing behaviour is going on **within** the dictionary too, but as the values are immutable it's less relevant.*

Comment: ahh much better than my explanation :P this man has a way with words :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley well... pictures!

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words though.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, variables in python act like labels. So, in the first example, you have a dictionary {1: 1, 2: 2}. That dictionary stays in memory. In the first example, A points to that dictionary, and you say B points to what A is pointing to (It won't point to the label A, but rather what the label A is pointing to).

In the second example, A and B are both pointing to this dictionary, but you point A to a new dictionary ({}). B stays pointing to the old dictionary in memory from the first example.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the dictionary A points to when you say `A={}` not destroying the old dictionary ... this sample should demonstrate for you

```
A={1:1} 
print id(A)
B = A
print id(B)
B[2] = 5
print id(B)
print A
print id(A)
A = {}
print id(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about the difference between creating a new dictionary and changing an existing dictionary.

```
A[2] = 2
```

Is modifying the dictionary by adding a new key, the existing stuff is still part of that dictionary.

```
A = {}
```

This creates a totally new empty dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this: A is the name of one object, then you make B a different name for that object. That's the first part, but then in the second code you make a new object and say ok that old object isn't called A anymore now this new object is called A.

B isn't pointing at A. B and A are both names for the same object, then names for two different objects.