# Python change objects in a list inplace

Tags: python

This might not make a lot of sense, but I'd like to change the following to show `'x'` instead of `'a'`

```
>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "b"
>>> c = "c"
>>> d = [a, b, c]
>>> d[0] = "x"
>>> a
'a'
```

Is it possible to have this behavior somehow? Not only for strings, but for other objects too.

Comment: Not without significant changes to Python itself. Strings are **immutable**, and therefore by definition *cannot be changed in-place*. Recommended reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said, python literals (numbers/strings) are immutable, only complex type like object/list is mutable,

Comment: @number5 that's not really accurate: [`complex` is a numeric type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)... There are mutable and immutable mappings and sequences, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what does this have to do with mutability? you can assign to a variable another value right? this is exactly what i'd like to do, its just the reference to the object is in the list

Comment: @iggy **everything**. To make the alteration in `d` affect `a`, you would have to change the object that they both reference in-place. This is *not possible* if the object that they both reference is immutable. `d = [a]` really means *"create a new list, the first element of which contains a reference to the object **currently** referenced by the identifier `a`"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, why does something like this work then? `>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "b"
>>> c = "c"
>>> d = [a, b, c]
>>> d[0] = "x"
>>> a
'a'
>>> a = "x"
>>> a
'x'
>>> d
['x', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: What do you mean *"why does it work"*?! Because you're **separately changing both `d[0]` *and* `a`!** Please read Ned Batchelder's article, which will hopefully clear up your confusion over how Python's assignments work.

Comment: A list is a collection (ordered sequence) of references. Your code doesn't work for the very same reason that `a = 'foo'`, `b = a`, then `b = 'bar'` doesn't work; rebinding one reference to point to a new object does not alter any other references to the old object. You cannot alter other references.

Comment: As simple as: you can only mutate mutable objects. Just for learning purposes, instead of a string, play with a `bytesarray` (which is mutable) and mutatete it from the reference stored in the list. Anyway, mutability is the source of a lot of evil, don't do that.

Comment: If you're still not convinced, try this, `a='a' ; l=[a] ; a='b' ; print l`

Comment: Related question on referencing confusion I answered yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29952200/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't  because when you assign `l=[a,b,c]`, you put the value of `a` in `l`, not `a`.

Perharps the closest thing:

```
class ref:
    value=0
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.value=x
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

a=ref('a')
b=ref('b')
c=ref('c') 
l=[a,b,c]
l[0].value='x'
print(a)
>>>> 'x'
```

Comment: thanks, seems you're one of the few that read the part about the other objects

Comment: This isn't correct, repr must return a string. (which isn't assured)

Comment: Whats the `value=0` for? This seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually doing is passing a, b and c to d[] as references. d then refers to those strings instead of the variables.

It doesn't care what a, b or c are equal to. You give an example in the comments but it actually doesn't work when run like this:

```
>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "b"
>>> c = "c"
>>> d = [a, b, c]
>>> a = "x"
>>> a
'x'
>>> d
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c = 12
>>> c
12
>>> d
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are intentionally immutable in Python.

Your options are to store the string in a mutable container, or to use some other data-type which is mutable.

This example stores each string inside a mutable container (your own class or another list for eg).

```
a = ["a"]
b = ["b"]
c = ["c"]
d = [a, b, c]
d[0][0] = "x"
a = d[0][0]
print(a)
```

Will print `"x"`

However in this case a `bytearray` might be a better choice.

```
a = bytearray(b'abc')
a[2] = ord(b'x')
a = chr(a[2])
print(a)
```

Will print "x" too.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are labels for objects.

`d` is a list of labels.

`a` is a label for an object. `'a'` is an immutable object. If you want to change `a` to show `'x'` you will have to change what it is pointing to:

```
>>> a = 'x'
>>> a
'x'
```

Or:

```
>>> a = d[0]
>>> a
'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is `x` :

```
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
d =[a,b,c]
d[0] = "x"
a = d[0]
print a
```

The output is `x`